# Error message: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature

Tags: angular, typescript

Only `action === 'enable'` in `if` is causing **'Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((value?: any, options?: Object)
=> void) | ((opts?: { onlySelf?: boolean; emitEvent?: boolean; }) => void)' has no compatible call signatures.'** error in the line of `formGroup.get`, if I remove this snippet on the `if` the error does not happen.

```
public act(action: string) {
   this.formGroup.get('field1')[action]();
   if (action === 'reset' || (this.userPermissions.field2 === true && action === 'enable')) {
      this.formGroup.get('field2')[action](); //error here <<<<<<<<<<<<
   }
}
```

At other times I call the function.

```
this.act('reset');
this.act('enable');
this.act('disable');
//etc
```

formGroup initiation

```
const formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
   field1: [{ value: undefined, disabled: false }, Validators.compose([])],
   field2: [
      { value: 'text' },
      Validators.compose([Validators.required])
      ],
....
return formGroup
```

Comment: show formGroup initiation

Comment: edited: formGroup initiation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using TypeScript 3.2 or below.  If you can update to TypeScript 3.3 or above, there is more [support for calling unions of functions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) and your code should hopefully not error at all:

```
// TS 3.3 or above
declare const f: ((value?: any, options?: Object) => void) | 
  ((opts?: { onlySelf?: boolean; emitEvent?: boolean; }) => void);
f(); // okay
```

[‍](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gMwFzwAoCA3KCAVxAH58oUBPAGniQAcMBLVNG+AeQBGAK3AYAlPAC8APnjEkHYBIA+hAmww98AbxYoI9AMogI2XgKRIIIOgG54IALYcMAUWIgUGc5et34AL4SMnIKSrYAUNgEYvYA9HEsANZQ9EA)

If you are stuck with an older version of TypeScript, the best way to deal with this is to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler that you are sure what you are doing is safe:

```
// TS 3.2 or below
declare const f: ((value?: any, options?: Object) => void) | 
  ((opts?: { onlySelf?: boolean; emitEvent?: boolean; }) => void);
f(); // error
(f as ()=>void)(); // okay
```

[‍](https://typescript-play.js.org/?ts=3.2.1#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gMwFzwAoCA3KCAVxAH58oUBPAGniQAcMBLVNG+AeQBGAK3AYAlPAC8APnjEkHYBIA+hAmww98AbxYoI9AMogI2XgKRIIIOgG54IALYcMAUWIgUGc5et34AL4SMnIKSrYAUNgEYvYA9HEOMDBIMBEE2PBQaIRiMvKKYjHxiUgA1lD0QA)

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: You are very sure